# How to colorize shapes in a loop?

Tags: java, libgdx

Why are both figures in the cycle painted in only one color?
while I need one to be painted in black and one in blue.
Thanks!

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha)
{
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

    renderer.setProjectionMatrix(Main.viewport.getCamera().combined);
    renderer.setTransformMatrix(batch.getTransformMatrix());
    renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);

    for (int i = 0; i < rect2.size(); i++)
    {
        renderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        renderer.rect(rect2.get(i).getX(), rect2.get(i).getY(),
                rect2.get(i).getWidth(), rect2.get(i).getHeight());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < enemy.size(); i++)
    {
        renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer.rect(enemy.get(i).getX(), enemy.get(i).getY(),
                enemy.get(i).getWidth(), enemy.get(i).getHeight());
    }
    renderer.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the LibGDX docs you can find a page about the `renderer` (as you named it) and how to color several shapes in different colors. By using `renderer.begin()` you set a shape. You then give all the properties of that shape (this includes dimensions and color and such). As soon as you use `renderer.end()` the shape will be drawn. When you then use the `renderer.begin()` again you define a new shape with new properties, where you can choose different dimensions and colors again.

Example code from the LibGDX docs:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html

```
 shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
 shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
 shapeRenderer.line(x, y, x2, y2);
 shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, width, height);
 shapeRenderer.circle(x, y, radius);
 shapeRenderer.end();

 shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
 shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
 shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, width, height);
 shapeRenderer.circle(x, y, radius);
 shapeRenderer.end();
```

tl;dr: End the `shapeRenderer` after every loop and begin an new one for the other loop.

Comment: Thanks Bro , I didn’t know about it (:

Comment: LibGDX might have a steep learning curve, but keep at it :) Maybe even try to build something with LibGDX artemis, it has nice additions and some performance tweaks in comparison to LibGDX alone: https://github.com/DaanVanYperen/libgdx-artemis-quickstart